# Converting blog to base64: TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an app previewing an image fetched via an API.

The fetched binary image data should be converted to base64 with the following codes.

However, I got an error saying "TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'".

I have no idea how to fix it. Please help.

```
export const fileToBase64 = (file: File | Blob): Promise<string> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
     resolve(reader.result as string);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onerror = reject;
  });
```

- Actual image data fetched

```
�PNG


IHDR����6�4jIDATx^�{l]Օ��   ���:�I��G��D�#
d 5-T�!u�(f��y��"f�hF<�IQL�r��0d��0<F;���y? �@n'q��v�_k��\;q�9���Ͻ����'}"~ܳ��k��}���C���sΩ�V
�b�8">��|����G!d���Za���ބ���Z���
B!`�fF�ҝD�ŵg���E!��&ŬR'Qz����xBHb�In�9�y�N�4^��z�nBq���͙��s#�-��}_;T�v"�'�  j�9�>I�Im��u�n?B))�I)�k[DҢn����Z�ەBbŜYw1-"!�d��Es]
!d�d����{z]���2(&��h�W�\h���:M�B9�93���Hh�E��ΙB�M
�4h��L����P��{K�N��T����Ľ�I*v�ךt�-E�+�V��w�O1��T�^;#=�q�>�핏��
�{L���#8��}}���q�{� b S:��O���Jqsf/*=p)uɌ�^\���93�����/����9BJ�9s�ߦ�I�o���B����4������s4f�H��9�>9GBH��㠴O�#!$_�qP%ב2&�W�8��3r�-B�c�,ý�(�Ǿ��f�qDH�0�  r=@(��ˉv�.l��6<���8�;��Z�3B�ɽ玣c�@��.�TF�7BCo'��R�<��$�ۻ�ۏPZZ1渷��{��Ń��c�ok�0�������+� ��"~`�w��ɽ�����Ft^J�;���0\�A�/r�q�+
_ϥ�71f+�x&��n�N��6��LH�1��:x&�+��˲�ϗ��
���2Y>~����ge��ɲ�/�R6�v�l�������8o�4e2���+r��N�6n��۷K�޽�y�t}�twt��������{���Y������]������,�L�l���>���3������<o�t4��:Fͥ�'+��B�N�
ӧ��;��s�H��e�����Һf����-�����|||&|6|F|V|f|v\�ׄk��KK&�4�)&w^�<J���|F�]�l���]�?.��9��Һv���f�����y�}�g�g�5�ZpM�6\#�u�
7׮�A�*�6�!�ex^Gѭ��R�|����&ң�����(�����*=����׊kƵ#�b���x���g!�`��U�����X9i�l���d��O��tu�JzAl#�
1C��`N��4g:���{Y�j��q��kd�w�+���i����SMM:O�<A��"��)b��ӂ�^Z�0���ź�ceÌ����]�_~Y�6m�ΣG��=:�B��DL[���hc�7�t{�a˽���0�;�]z��ewm����hiq⍨��X#���h��n'����!Cc;ʴ�Dq�1����W]%;�_Z���S�52J�-�&h��
m�ۑ�4�/9���y�NC�����&���K�%�GS�i�Fh+�ڎ�
[މ�0�s�Y^����~$������#�mx�m�6����6�����9���y�g���{.X��u�8'�mC�%�m�6��NC�|r�x��A{�sr����ߔ�o��;��6F[�����+R�4br��<�#�e^(k��Fv�w���K�
pr6h�#˖}}}B�����4�����viY����F���_ȱM�x�A�>���>���>��

r   �H0��V���oy����`B{0�p
����
'�C"��qV�AG4|j�*�)S��,���9��H�W�g�wЇt�J�,"I�p��u_,o�U���I���:?��;�lB_B���,�rN$i�A
�<��k�ܵ��s4�[�>���>����[J�HR0��\u�Ҵpan��[���A�B�jz�yY��υ�_
圈�#6=��Ɋ    ��Sq�*!���Ν����++yN ������y`ػw�%��~�oU���u$�^]���ߤ}�-Ή�̤t�+�7L�.���t9��5!%��,Z���j眈/��y`���T:�<q�`~��I���h眈렁".��]t�l�9S������8�覯=賺�DW1�2u�%چ�S��g?N�#��W�y&軺?����[�L����
`�]���������>����<O�5L��0_UU%^|Q�Z[��$�+Їїѧu?O�<c�L��0_v���,Ƕl���A�F�F��>��ͬ�Ĥ��2Y]]-�}�w$��o�����h"�DF��9���+f̐Co�Ƀ�H�  ھ�>����C�H�1)���~�r��Iz��!I    ������z<$TΉ�
�1ֹ������   d߯��!�b�o~��<�BN�����@��'Fܶ���W���W�z.I=)x�5W�;#6��AO����w��=i۰�[�����F
�Dju�#1��Z;#������ΣG��!�X060F��/r�H�؀VXG��_T+'O���=Y2#+3    �A���y�i]�D���k�y�B�cccG�����"2RL��<�|��Һn�=z�BÎ���$߉�|H�IDP�o�l��9����a�1����7�t>$yb�Wim��]��R8��2r�=<�TB�B�����
X��>"�^[�%�ѿ�+��%$f0�0�0���K�ȅ�:O�������b5��_�J�O��}�[{�KY>~|h�%��'I&�g���ţ)���S�t�'��Hw{�4-\�9==�g�8��_C����f����5���މ���Iؙ�+'N���?��AH�   �������s�:o�s�⑨�=V_u�|�%{O��AȨ`�� Ƣ���C4&a�{�t\n�H��1����;�҇I������u�!�`�"&�6'��C@o tp�o~p��XO��Y<?$"(^�w���A��`l&�ND��Ta���_�� �B�cc���KC��S�u^M��3��Nn��p�9!����1����2:�&�������9s���!�G  !�1����>)���k�,��������ٳ��@ !��a��pB���y6����u��[��y�x�0Ʋ�����".�/�_+8J�u�z�    !�����;�o�ɭ8]�O��4I�_y�����XƘ^9yrh�{hrW��7K�[-���N� !�1����7��:�&{a��Έ�¥����Y<I(���z�{$rl�ο^c<�j�1���Ot�#�$�q�u�y�<�F�a/�Ra]q�~h��p�Mrl�V��!   ccc?��9�B�c�Qqq޸����Лor�+BR�:�<ƾ��Y��w؋h��0ov��!�c~���|���:{����slq��~��!$El��^߷;�wq����ݲ2�p�-\iNH�9��$f��y�aV�e/0�q�3����=I9}�!���Cy��<C�x�];�z�����}��B�v=��ϋ3:?;�����
7�,]���BRrr��Y�s���_�]u�rl�f�wH�h�d�*I.�
�:ox��B�\�᝷n�X9������p�\�VSs����V�>|��#�+t�{b�����'�ѕ߬�6MVUU�օ�(��&|F�/����=��u!��u
S�H�;��B�Nf���m����V����A�N
��'��.�x��c�Eɞy�8x�h}}0ǰ��6ԆI׆kĵwA�h��Ϥ��݆��y�  ���>6Μ)�ͺ�G�K��=�a�k��n�&--A��m�n�1��Xv��e�Q0��9�fi1�D�� w ��6����ߣ����o���'t� ���0�Ql#�1�r�/k`��㣂��������Ǻ?����<���I��h��b�ؑѥ��A_��.�x�pp�����/HOW��������Y�B�C�����9��_r�n��������(+��w�%���@J��ŋ�Y��}�LS2: � �x�c��1��X>a���u E�s��s$�r�
�[t{����%�x��c�~�GW%�Ď��(��5bNJr��+�g�^2�gd�Irr�n����`-�G�E̹��� ���<9����y�$�_\k��@Ί��Ii�:7�:�҂���q��ku~/*&��W��z>.x���F|m��!�9�F��q��K�J��l�`��p���7�t�[�m���\���c�5:�
����g̐��v�&1�����Ş�%�mE�r
r������<_L�����8�e�ϊtw�v&1���<gg��G��mG���5�9�<��^����/��˝��/~1�9����7�K���y�4�ܣ����t����_�ee����uے�5؋iyee8��+цhK������[���}��_�k���:vL�+�[&\ב8Ѧ|K1^�{��t�]V��X���^�Bg����K/�6%#d�ĉ�X�D��%���]H����a<Zy���>b�d�H�hc�����o�!g���&7y���W�.�@�s�����I
�{Y�K��A�E�\��d�����5�\#m�6�$�9�t�9��@.BN�1v،��#?4�9'�G��G?���c���9�x@.BN�������#�x���%y�m݆d�p΃BΉ�r�g����:P0�a��I7}��}�n?28�A��9�����ܤc�5���A�ƣ�w���n;28�A����An�quX��J]���!U?�I��e�y5B�؊$�DFrr����V�z0l�/{_���>U0����9����\���#�7�:������<�p�H� G!W阺���F�@W����I����E����xR:��3d� G}����骺���y�e��������^d��g�RD��������tL�'{_�0x��,"�ǳG�Y]�����;w�?W�N���t8���\��������ya�q��-�:%n[^{M��aN�g�r�'��Pf��0$Ɠ��������M�����x��D_B�"����ܥc�]�����D�
���l(���!���.CG���0(���o`�b��ͺ]� 쩭
ő�8D�"�����<jA��b<�<�
�tu�v!��ܹ�R��c$?z��}:3�F׉�G�����ӺM� �+Zl�V���3o^(��Z��D$��X�F���;V�o߮ۃ����P)-��k$?�Ð�t5a��!�'��n�>]:ZZt{�<[�D=�{�9�L��Q�t��/��F�������ޮۃ(x�
y~H~ �!���9j��!�E����^����  _ۥ�%_�͏`o�q�B�s�*]/BD|�s���ji۸Q��@ǎ�RJ��9M��Eu����9��d�wJ�#����Cr��� �!�!������!�7���ϗ�=ĭ����і����eY�Ӑ�t�\S׋�\3�<��Wuty�ʕ&X�A.._6W���,�۷�L��}�t�I?�Q��Y�B��t4D_䆧����rҤP�4���i�����f���!���5y�؜���[CqsЬ���?F|�S�z�1z����.�u!C����CqsЬ���?F|�S~��;:�\�A]��B�u͚P�4��F������K.��C�cF�K��AnC��1sЌ�^�ͷݦcN:f��$�83����E������|�wp<�����E9�t��7�R�����A��1sЌ.��_��?�iiol��&���</d`���t�������"�\w�u�q�7���"�� �!��9h�W��_�Z[u���h}����ŌRE_E�%a���t�ԯ��G���)o"\yN��+ӣ���]�>����S@��w�X�HǚXz:;eOmm(f��,�,�. �\���c����_.��xCǙW�S���h���t�3W@�TZ�#���L   ���0, �WY@�A�C���rLԌJ���t�
7�,'w��q&�B��$�9O��A��( [���<zTǙ�.�~K� �m��P�ԃRV&�Ϟ-=��:�DX@�ߒl��>g����P����s�q^0�FǋR�$�d~؇3��/ uc�ʾ��VǗXxp�]�af���RWQ��c�_@�Ǎ��%Kt|�p�D��\1�<�>/�t��,?^>Y�ZǗ�_�h���t�3( N�»�+��_�,����AEF_&g���ܧ�嘋Q@��t�U�'K���:�����Ҥ��y� �!��X�����K_ұ%�B�#H4�}:V��|�����a�ɑ$�M3g�b���mw߭�J��&G�h��t�\�����a�ɑ$�>+�t�����Ou\S��I�L����S�8���d�s�鸦�4Y@� ��8������/븦�4Y@� ��8����1:����&M�0G�.
��5�/ �k�긦�4Y@� ��8�����{�鸦�4Y@� ��8�������:����&M�0�}:N��|�hi�qM=, 4i���A��qrM�HWk��k�a�I�$r���k��xM�, aX@b���C�5���Ф��O��5�/ $M�, ��8�&����Ф����k:_@�+M�, a�+9���&M�0�D�A�0, 4i���a�A.$�B�&H.$�Ane��&M�0��$��b�4Y@�p3��v�aX@h�d   ���c�J�a�I�$��Ai��&M�0<�6q�<9�4Y@� ��8���d�SO鸦�4Y@� ��8������q%�m55�XQ���$r���k:_@��}��+�Y@�A�ӱrM�Ȧ�3u\������
r���k:_@��%W", 49��D�ܧc���U�'K���:����&E�0�y�}:V���X�O�\q�r2���M=�,����P�(�I�a�er6�y�}:^���*��q�������:�Ĳ��*/J}}��A�C���r�*�H��qҲd��/�, � �!��x9�����~�[_bY?mZ(^��$�0   �o�|Q�_@���dzHǗ���E�O�h�?�>/�t����2y�l����1&�B��D`s��9sĔ������|G:��a&�B���A��r��X9�d��7�U�@\t�(�A��h�</
H��>���a�i]�FǙ�W�h���t�5��`��&��q��ˡ7��q&�B��$�:�</Ǭ    ��d�y�ɁE�t�����S��ֆbF�ˢϢ�0�u�y:f��O��}Tz::t����)�<@*�8�:/�������KWk��7������ա�Q���$rr�����U@�]w�t<��Mz������� ǭ��WC1sг
H�q|W�����76�x�^X@�/��rr���c�VT�. �E$�Nyd�Ro�n�H]��'Αe�B1s��Y�×���t�I?>�;73J]}������A3�~xQ@6�v��7Q�Q�dp6�~{(f���ËR�%��եcN��cF�K��An����P�4��G���l�;ekC��;�W�SW�����&:f��u�4�ǈop�ݜ���f4E�}}��'�Y]7N�����x��^�GǞ�+өkr��؜�ܦ��Y]7N����\9i���ۧ�O����&[g�
Ŏ��}}�L���AnӱsЬ�g�
NY�e���k:�D��%�����}���
rr���k�zB�k�>#������h˅�y`sr�g���!�78gY�l��N�<rD7Q\�8?JK(� �2�4�6?���"��]s��Ҷq�n�����
rr�����z�xpFz��qr�t;��.���\���6�!���9h��!�E��;|P���u[ׅ�ѐ�>�9�L��Q�t��/��F��0}�t���� �ر�E��L�5�924�a�e:��Z��E�Ec�s#��)�Ǝ��۷�� ��Bh��y���\�c蠨 ct���xpB!�3o�n2|��[��;<��t�F׉�G��\���HOw�n2</�[.��.�0CG��ub@�W[�#~�Sb�k��ͺ]� 쩭
ő�8D�"�����n�պN���|��O~�ۅ_�Œ���.CG���0$�����|�ܨm�`up]EE(��"�W��,�.KG���0$��f[�"~�Srs��ؿ`���C�Kdx��y��Հٺ>��`{w<C�q����٩ۈ�ʢ#�o]
�*�,O�?��.�
�9�:'.F{cc(��G�!2<<[؛�u!o�obA�
{cq��a����2SJ}�ţl�B������uaXD�@'���?����us�<��t����@�B���tU]���������_D��-5e�ȸp����tL]U׃ac�4�C���\�͟�ۋ� vN]9qb8���}���rr����N��`�Ov�
_���tt�6#ÀE�$�)�&�(W����`��Ri<�L��^]�<?�F��=Fr����"�W�zPƓ��o|C�O��mG��Dh9�1r����tl�Fׁ����N������n?2L8'B!�<�9ɳ��ktƓ�������Ǖ�1�"�^9���s��<Yy3:���Ј_�k��F�6m��H
�s"�s�q�梵6'�;lF��cr��6G�2�\v������H��G|��c�/~�$gGE���QO�Ƃ�o��A��D�!�<�%�����P�6��~l�^�5ee���H���$W�y����_r���Îl﫡���Ί�mJF�D�)�<��g�_�U(�.��}��_贶�7-\�ە�<�fz���H#D�-9�?�&�~�}����c|��׆/~Q:�mKb���/7 -�9�=:ގ[�����_2�x�6�;V�>��Hw�ncH@8�����#�
m��Q$l�A�A�ѱwX��:����t�q�9�k�nf#<c�y�y�A�A�ѱw���~Y�pֺ�/����suz�9�xq(��-�F�x � � ���;n���E���
���믿�o����٬쩭
ş��h�
).�[�7����"�W�<_T�/��vF|g�_�4|8wn�]�-�h�)
��{.���^��{I0�L��&O���w�6'Ed[M
׍���9bOJG��-�1�-7��z��/��@N�}�����mO���*��˪� �l���P[x�,��K�ɽҫ?��.�0A��Ϻ�I���a<���A�1�\_�ANYas�n��9���Ѩ?�Ӗ��ֻ��Çu %o�ټG�#8+b�X�����9ŷU��F��K��U�i��/��"e�2���:kV�}h~"v� ]�C�K�St�x`���%��^�]��v��7K����?������9��E�3Ď�.�!�O��"g���݁0�-,�������?�Q�s$��9���䓾>���y|T1y�'N  ;�u�����$'�q�˱w�����ft�u쇚mm���N�q�L�E�0X�WWW��.��Z����IGKK�;t�y r�l����x�.d�Eɞy�O������'y�\��J����g���݆��y����B`Ô)��Р�  q^�����7�_���䊆�SCm鉥ٲ�P�o�Bz�
���V�W�G��$�����f�:�>��� G W�v���_�1��u!��x��_��`�o.�O��q�'��r�gE��J�k������^���+���ͺϐ�9�bJ�˱-[���'���c0�c�q^��|�E�r����ѹ�i���B�.�]�<"=�BRr��G
r�������y���B�ꫮ�Co�)=�ݺ/BRrr����]�1��u!�ee��[�����?BRĩ�&�0c��;����y����B��s�
^�#���\��G���c(���B�ܿ`x�20�=<�\�����0��W\~9�CI���[oc_�Ϭ���;��煜��\6�tw�%$%`�]�y��P>�G?�}����b;
�*��B�
���{�qb�Z������vF\�.��p�^B��6�8ƺ��[��o"0����+X��E����1�����b�>�:�&{q�".�+WN�,ͯ�b{\��c�y�YeǶ�:K��Dq�~YV&k��VZׯ�ݐ�!��/<�η���6������W��9�[������P�T�
�����@�����gKǡC�OB<cc8  w&io]
���jk}D�2����Q:��}��0��|�]Ϸ)���Z��Dc<��]������'t%�8��G��/�����S3:�����X饲������v�W   !�1��W�
ƬǞZ��j����.?^�.�Y�8
�&��X���Wu>M���o�+&L����"B�S`Lblb��q�su>M��3Ե����+�
    q�y,\��;�˙ct>M%&�B���o�\9q�|�%����]�RB011&�8�X��d�8.��3ԣĹ�踼!d��cccQ�O�����bc<�lQ��z�8�s"����    ��y��Λ���������g!�D�v�%lΣ�tlWR(�I�^Y�śM���t�:��:!$F��w  {�
�g���b��W�r�����}�+�    )[XЛ�;��'���앥��������{g3S[cz�%���u5Rl�*����Z쿳��{���E�BH`,aL%ho��"V��H�$"�ދ@�����<BF���v,%dWݐ:�ab��X5��ٴ�[ǵ"�;f0v�à�q�G��u>$���º "��Gi���O��٩�!$����ڈ1���*t>$�@�߉��<Y���,"���
�L��<�G�؀�Z;#���]p��~�  �<zT�B�cccE���W���6"����E������m�ȍ  �cc���}/�w}�x���ߣ��$뮿^Z^{���H�  �;�X��H�V�����$���H�_Y�����F�'BR��B
�<x�G�0 ;?d0�@�TS7c$�}}~�?�Ch<$T��QjL��Hܶo�1C����tt�FH�@G_�x�ixdy��harw"�A���}_]]-�{L�Z[��#$�o�������U���MlL�h�D��7�r�۲E�=B�}};��j��|FF��9���J��"�F����/�O�~�`9��&%s"}�UT��9s�������@�E��K"�˺'X�y��Iؙ���0u�4>���'ހ��>����s
��E�$�L�|���"���������c��@E_E���8%�XZ�A������8Pg�SOI����
�8�"�$�fB}�G�i�&�f֎�FL�Kǌ�
��"����\2�t47ˁE�d���A���5%"�+�@���މ����˻w�%G��*vRr����.[�C��3���"��X<|ĤtN�ee�b�M��ݻ�'�(�عS�������4-H>��4�I�H����R�.)p~��M0�a�����}.��R(�<��I�v��7��瞓��v���)��/�O�o���R9�4Р�w"�u�\lV��׿��ÇuJ $/�wЇЗЧt?K���H*&�s"ʺ�c�a�i�����q��}}}}H�����VI
lx'r�������Wrs$��(�'�7�G�W�gB�(�r�#-ΉD���L�O�&{�K9�y3       �������렏�~C9�:���w"�b���k�����r���Y��9�}}!�+ȇ�si�pNdP�r7�r����w$)m��F���S�z<_��*͠��.���
� ��d�5��k���+�'N�lӣ��
ۆhK�)�m��C�\�5,����D
��<8rt���K��('>��w&�6Cۡ
і���/81��<σDc�r�zLb���7�$;~�ci�ӟ��Ot�"��6B[���v)ߧ�y� ��3�����Ǎ��W]�5ۺf
�J"8�϶Ip�a��V��(HN���1);c=n��{����j����rb��8tH���u^#E�F�{��5�&��h��s2<�Db�]c���=$�/�,m�6I�ѣ���K��E��`{�t�5^,9�A
���D�Ft*Z���]�5�u�,�>�pp^ĩ�&�I� v�!b��"����;-X�}�y�±hLoGҝ�jY�,�ԧ�d�r�$�4sfp�i���<�j��B�;��䫷��1?F�B
�v�ZkgDG�1���El��|R�._.퍍�L]���X�kĵ�q�b����$b����OȈAǲ.��t�Hb5��nN������/ȡ�ޒ�u�s(�l��O���׀k�5��p���'�f\��-��,�x�Va]��h    \v���ⳟ���Se�-����~W�ϙ#���?�����ׂWV���q��/|||&|6|F|V|f|v\�ׄk��KK&�t���:�ᝈ;���x��y��J��q�/^'�t���_�;|P�͓�LF��,��uurl�&9��Ҿo�t9,��ZÂ�����k�=�^��,�L�l��.�N�n|||&|6|�`΂��]c�Ń���#:$��}�x&���NXi��蜔RwŘ��㙐�c;b����|J]cc�Z�cBF��E(u]n�N���|J]��w�0�K�R�^V�O�Ңt4�^V�o�Ңt4�^V$Y��Ki���㎐�`;x�<��SJc*��!��p��q�u$���t���\�nL�m���y#�%�H���*B������RzF��A�@���\�7B��bL���BQ��y#U�[�S�1����:.�{k��ɽ����[+1�(M�ý�)�s$4�r���R`8GB�#�8-�H�r���0�#�~�1�� �M�H��r��0�#���9B|�p�-Z:�W!I����Z1�)�C�-�UEHR1��[�'�<���Ծ�8 S�L�`<���t��Ϡ��U\BHPPp,h��΄�E���9N�$�����P'�.3�N���BŜy����\h2E[���!��L*M�7�Nt¡�m�6���O!�b�̙@���}{Qeu�BH�1g��|��h�L�܋��&6AU�3s'|Ex�D��ڡZ�!�8�M\cL�z�:��x��1�=!$1�3s(}�H�6�_OBI-��s�>Ӽw�=�_/B!`�޻��I��?��Bɽ�!$n̙u)�ҝ>��|���%�����Y��IEND�B`�
```

I tried with the following, but it doesn't show any image.

```
reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([file], { type: fileType }));
```

(The `fileType` is passed as an argument.)

Comment: How are you retrieving the image data? If you're using XMLHttpRequest, you can use `xhr.responseType = "blob";` or if you use `fetch`, you can use `await response.blob()`

Comment: The `Blob` constructor accepts strings, but only Unicode strings (for creating text files), not binary strings. [Binary strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString/Binary) are a weird JS concept where bytes are stored not as bytes but as codepoints in a string. They're less efficient than ArrayBuffers/Blobs and can generally be avoided.

Comment: @1j01 Thank you for your advice.
I use `axios.get()` to retrieve the image data.
Following your advice, I set `responseType: 'blob'` and it worked! Thank you!!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export const fileToBase64 = (file: File | Blob): Promise<string> =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
     resolve(reader.result as string);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onerror = reject;
  });
```

```
const base64String = await fileToBase64(
  (
    await axios.get('endpoint url', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        Accept: 'application/octet-stream',
      },
      responseType: 'blob',
    })
  ).data as Blob
)
```